# Video duration is the double of what it should be

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, accord.net

I was trying to record my computer screen, for that I am using Accord.

I had everything working fine with the Accord version 3.8.0.0, but when I upgraded to the version 3.8.2.0-alpha my recording videos are slow down, and they take approximately the double to finish.

So a 10 second video actually takes 20 seconds to play (in the video player the duration of the video is also 10 seconds).

I searched in google and didn't managed to find anything usefull. Probably due to the alpha version of the release.

I managed to find a project from one of the maintainers of the Accord project that uses this 3.8.2.0-alpha version: https://github.com/cesarsouza/screencast-capture

I downloaded the zip file, extracted the project, built the project, fixed a compilation error (change a `Dispose()` to `Stop()`) and then ran the application, but the problem still exists... the generated video files are still slow down...

The main methods of my code with the 3.8.2.0-alpha version are these (they were taken from the previous project I downloaded):

```
public void StartRecording()
{
    if (IsRecording || !IsPlaying)
        return;

    int height = area.Height;
    int width = area.Width;
    Rational framerate = new Rational(1000, screenStream.FrameInterval);
    int videoBitRate = 1200 * 1000;

    OutputPath = Path.Combine(main.CurrentDirectory, fileName);
    RecordingStartTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    videoWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
    videoWriter.BitRate = videoBitRate;
    videoWriter.FrameRate = framerate;
    videoWriter.Width = width;
    videoWriter.Height = height;
    videoWriter.VideoCodec = VideoCodec.H264;
    videoWriter.VideoOptions["crf"] = "18";
    videoWriter.VideoOptions["preset"] = "veryfast";
    videoWriter.VideoOptions["tune"] = "zerolatency";
    videoWriter.VideoOptions["x264opts"] = "no-mbtree:sliced-threads:sync-lookahead=0";

    videoWriter.Open(OutputPath);

    HasRecorded = false;
    IsRecording = true;
}

void VideoPlayer_NewFrameReceived(object sender, Accord.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    DateTime currentFrameTime = eventArgs.CaptureFinished;

    // Encode the last frame at the same time we prepare the new one
    Task.WaitAll(
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (syncObj) // Save the frame to the video file.
            {
                if (IsRecording)
                {
                    if (RecordingStartTime == DateTime.MinValue)
                        RecordingStartTime = DateTime.Now;

                    TimeSpan timestamp = currentFrameTime - RecordingStartTime;
                    if (timestamp > TimeSpan.Zero)
                        videoWriter.WriteVideoFrame(this.lastFrame, timestamp, this.lastFrameRegion);
                }
            }
        }),

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Adjust the window according to the current capture
            // mode. Also adjusts to keep even widths and heights.
            CaptureRegion = AdjustWindow();

            // Crop the image if the mode requires it
            if (CaptureMode == CaptureRegionOption.Fixed ||
                CaptureMode == CaptureRegionOption.Window)
            {
                crop.Rectangle = CaptureRegion;

                eventArgs.Frame = croppedImage = crop.Apply(eventArgs.Frame, croppedImage);
                eventArgs.FrameSize = crop.Rectangle.Size;
            }

            //// Draw extra information on the screen
            bool captureMouse = Settings.Default.CaptureMouse;
            bool captureClick = Settings.Default.CaptureClick;
            bool captureKeys = Settings.Default.CaptureKeys;

            if (captureMouse || captureClick || captureKeys)
            {
                cursorCapture.CaptureRegion = CaptureRegion;
                clickCapture.CaptureRegion = CaptureRegion;
                keyCapture.Font = Settings.Default.KeyboardFont;

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(eventArgs.Frame))
                {
                    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;

                    float invWidth = 1; // / widthScale;
                    float invHeight = 1; // / heightScale;

                    if (captureMouse)
                        cursorCapture.Draw(g, invWidth, invHeight);

                    if (captureClick)
                        clickCapture.Draw(g, invWidth, invHeight);

                    if (captureKeys)
                        keyCapture.Draw(g, invWidth, invHeight);
                }
            }
        })
    );

    // Save the just processed frame and mark it to be encoded in the next iteration:
    lastFrame = eventArgs.Frame.Copy(lastFrame);

    lastFrameRegion = new Rectangle(0, 0, eventArgs.FrameSize.Width, eventArgs.Frame.Height);
}
```

Anyone knows what might be problem causing this slow down?

**EDIT:**

I think I managed to find my problem:

```
pts:4.032000e+003   pts_time:0.252  dts:2.016000e+003   dts_time:0.126  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:6.720000e+003   pts_time:0.42   dts:3.360000e+003   dts_time:0.21   duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:1.075200e+004   pts_time:0.672  dts:5.376000e+003   dts_time:0.336  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:1.344000e+004   pts_time:0.84   dts:6.720000e+003   dts_time:0.42   duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:1.612800e+004   pts_time:1.008  dts:8.064000e+003   dts_time:0.504  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:1.881600e+004   pts_time:1.176  dts:9.408000e+003   dts_time:0.588  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:2.150400e+004   pts_time:1.344  dts:1.075200e+004   dts_time:0.672  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:2.553600e+004   pts_time:1.596  dts:1.276800e+004   dts_time:0.798  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:2.822400e+004   pts_time:1.764  dts:1.411200e+004   dts_time:0.882  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:3.091200e+004   pts_time:1.932  dts:1.545600e+004   dts_time:0.966  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:3.494400e+004   pts_time:2.184  dts:1.747200e+004   dts_time:1.092  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:3.897600e+004   pts_time:2.436  dts:1.948800e+004   dts_time:1.218  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:4.166400e+004   pts_time:2.604  dts:2.083200e+004   dts_time:1.302  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:4.704000e+004   pts_time:2.94   dts:2.352000e+004   dts_time:1.47   duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
pts:5.107200e+004   pts_time:3.192  dts:2.553600e+004   dts_time:1.596  duration:6.720000e+002  duration_time:0.042 stream_index:0
```

The PTS is always the double of DTS, that's why the video is presented in a slow down way.

Unfortunately I have no idea why this happens... Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug within the alpha release. [See here for more information.](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/1474)

You can always edit the source code and build the project with the corrections you added, however, that might require you to release whatever code you are using as LGPL if I understand the license correctly. But please do not take my word on this, as I am not a lawyer.

A possible fix that avoids the legal problems would be to merely downgrade to the last official release, as the bug is not present in there.

Comment: You are wrong regarding your first comment, I am still working on this project (very big one)  :D  That post is actually mine. At the time downgrading wasn't an option because I needed to record in the H264 format. I ended up implementing my own recorder using FFmpeg and passing the video feed using a pipe.

Comment: Oh alright. If you don't mind, would you point us in the direction that you went with some source code? We have been trying to find a solution for about two weeks now. We're trying to use non-GPL code though.

Comment: At the time I took ideas from here: https://github.com/MathewSachin/Captura 
From what I recall it starts a ffmpeg process and sets the input from a pipeline with a certain name, then in the application, a pipeline with the same name is created, and each frame is then provided to it. When you create the ffmpeg process you can specify everything you want regarding the record format. I think the link can help you.

Comment: Alright thank you so much! I think we're gonna take that route as well.